# Which rich text editor is most reliable and betted for android?

Tags: android, java

I am working on a medium clone app for which i will be needing a rich text editor to let users enter different types of data they want to add.

from different types i mean BOLD, ITALICS, NUMBERED LISTS, QUOTES, LINKS, IMAGES, DIVIDER LINE.

So far i have used 2 editors but both of them gave an error which resulted in crashing app.

editors that i used were https://github.com/irshuLx/Android-WYSIWYG-Editor and https://github.com/bxute/MarkDEditor.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: What features do you need (e.g. formatting, Markdown rendering, support for images)? What license should it use (so it doesn't clash with yours)?

Comment: What is *clone app cor*? Which two ones have you tried - so that you don't again get recommendations for them? Free, probably (add [gratis] tag)?

Comment: @Jan Doggen   sorry that was spelling error and read the question now for more information.